# How do I do this withColumn operation in Python-Spark? Maybe with user defined functions?

Tags: python, apache-spark

So the problem is that I have a dataframe which looks like this:

```
Year Month Day
2001 04    22
2001 05.   03
2002 01.   30
```

And I want to add an another Column, while doint opearations with the 3 column above.

```
another_date_variable = "2000-01-01"
```

Like this:

```
df.withColumn("DATE_DIFF", dt.datetime.strptime(F.col("YEAR")+"-"+F.col("MONTH")+"-"+F.col("DAY"), "%Y-%m-%d")-another_date_variable)
```

Code may not be syntax compatible, but the logic can be derived.

So basically what I want to do is to concat those 3 date columns, convert them to date, and substract it from a given date variable. And I will get the DATE_DIFFERENCE column, with the actual date difference in every row. Howewer, I find it so hard to do this, because of sparks unique types.

Every help is much appreciated.

Comment: There is the concat_ws built-in method for this kind of problems. https://spark.apache.org/docs/3.1.2/api/python/reference/api/pyspark.sql.functions.concat_ws.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One solution can be implemented as below:

```scala
// Assume we have a dataframe like this
var df = spark.sparkContext.parallelize(Seq(
  ("2001", "04", "22"),
  ("2001", "05.", "03"),
  ("2002", "01.", "30")
)).toDF("Year", "Month", "Day")

df = df
  // First we want to cast to integer because you have dots in your 'Month'
  .withColumn("Month", col("Month").cast("int"))
  // Then we concatenate the columns above and cast them to date through 'to_date'
  .withColumn("date", to_date(concat_ws("-", col("Year"), col("Month"), col("Day"))))
  // Creating our another_date_variable column in our dataset
  .withColumn("another_date_variable", to_date(lit("2000-01-01")))
  // Finding date differences between our 'date' and 'another_date_variable'
  .withColumn("diff", datediff(col("date"), col("another_date_variable")))
```

Final output:

```
+----+-----+---+----------+---------------------+----+
|Year|Month|Day|date      |another_date_variable|diff|
+----+-----+---+----------+---------------------+----+
|2001|4    |22 |2001-04-22|2000-01-01           |477 |
|2001|5    |3  |2001-05-03|2000-01-01           |488 |
|2002|1    |30 |2002-01-30|2000-01-01           |760 |
+----+-----+---+----------+---------------------+----+
```

Good luck!